# What are the highest skill level sets on tiny tower?

Tags: tiny-tower

I have been trying to get the best skill sets for each of my bitizens and the best I can find is 98798 and 89789 but they are only for blue and purple stores. What are the best/highest combinations for the other jobs so I have the strongest skill level for all of them?

Answer (score 1):

There are only a limited number of preset skill distributions.  I think those two are the best overall distributions, thought there's one with three 9s and lower values.

A better strategy is to aim for people that have 9's in the skills you need and to ignore the other skills.  They can only use one skill at a time anyway.